# React Class Component - How To add apply filter function to buttons

Tags: reactjs, filter

Using class components how would you add a filter function to the buttons below that would filter the products based on the category?

```
**productList.js**
export const  ProductList =[
    {
        id:0,
        category:"accessories",
        image:"./prod_images/accessory1.jpg",
        product: "product#1",
        description: "product#1",
        price: 0.00
}, //There are other objects with categories of collectables, jerseys...etc


**products.js**  //This renders the products
class Products extends Component{
    render(){
      
   
       return(
<>
{

          
            <div className="container prod-cntr" >
            <div className = "row prod-row">
    {ProductList.map(element =>( 
            <div className = "col-lg-3 prod-col" key={element.id}>
            <div className = "card card-container">
            <img src = {element.image} alt ="product img" className="prod-img"/>
            <div className="card-body">
            <p className ="card-title">{element.product}</p>
            <p className ="card-text">{element.description}</p>
            <p className ="prod-price">{element.price}  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCartPlus} className="prod-carticon"/></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>))}
            </div>
            </div>
}



**ButtonMenu.js** //these buttons need functions that will filter the products based on the category and only display the products that match that selection

class ButtonMenu extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <>
            <div className = "button Menu-container">
<button  className = "main-btn" value = "all">ALL</button>
<button  className = "main-btn" value = "men">Men</button>
<button  className = "main-btn" value = "women">Women</button>
<button  className = "main-btn" value = "jerseys">Jerseys</button>
<button  className = "main-btn" value = "shirts">Shirts</button>
<button  className = "main-btn" value = "accessories">Accessories</button>
<button  className = "main-btn" value = "collectables">Collectables</button>
</div>

            </>
        )
    }
}

export default ButtonMenu;
```

Can you please assist? (I need to do this with class components to help fully understand class components. I will do the same with functions later). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I optimized your code as you can see the below code.
I make `ProductList` component and import into ButtonMenu component where you need to show the ProductList, I pass the data props in `Products` component as you can see the below code.

you need to make a state, where you store productList, then you show data with the state as  you can see I create a state `product`, because when you show the against category product list, you need to `filter` the data against category as you can see in the `getCatgory` function, then you need to set the updated data in `product`, after you can see the list of product against category which you choose.

**Noted:** class component 'functions', like functional components 'functions', but in the class component 'function' you do not use the const variable before the name of the function and you call the function with the `this` keyword.

This is your Button ButtonMenu.js Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Products from "./ProductList";

const ProductList = [
  {
    id: 0,
    category: "accessories",
    image: "./prod_images/accessory1.jpg",
    product: "product#1",
    description: "product#1",
    price: 0.0
  }
];

const CATEGORIES = [
  "ALL",
  "Men",
  "Women",
  "Jerseys",
  "Shirts",
  "Accessories",
  "Collectables"
];

class ButtonMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: ProductList
    };
  }

  getCategory = (category) => {
    if (category === "all") {
      this.setState({ products: ProductList });
    } else {
      const filter = ProductList.filter((d) => d.category === category);
      if (filter) {
        this.setState({ products: filter });
      }
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="button Menu-container">
          <Products products={this.state.products} />
          {CATEGORIES.map((item) => (
            <button
              className="main-btn"
              onClick={() => this.getCategory(item.toLowerCase())}
              value={item.toLowerCase()}
            >
              {item}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default ButtonMenu;
```

This your ProductList component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Products extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.products);
    return (
      <div className="container prod-cntr">
        <div className="row prod-row">
          {this.props.products.map((element) => (
            <div className="col-lg-3 prod-col" key={element.id}>
              <div className="card card-container">
                <img
                  src={element.image}
                  alt="product img"
                  className="prod-img"
                />
                <div className="card-body">
                  <p className="card-title">{element.product}</p>
                  <p className="card-text">{element.description}</p>
                  <p className="prod-price">{element.price}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Products;
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, I'm sure this is very close but even after going back and pasting this in to sure there were no typo's I'm receiving an error message stating :
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: array.

Check your code at ButtonMenu.js:432.
    at ButtonMenu (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:502:5)
    at div
    at App

Comment: Here is another error message:  react-dom.development.js:28439 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: hey Ahmad, I have a few more questions. in the Button menu code what does "|| [ ]" do? I have not seen that before.  Also in the filter, why use d & d.category?   Also do you know why super has a strike through through it. Is that why the code isn't working?

Comment: that `ProductList || []` means if you don't have `ProductList` then state will get the empty array, this is for example.

Comment: we are using `filter` on `ProductList`, in `filter` function `d.category` matching the category for against whose category which category against we want result, as you can see the code Iam declaring the `filter` in `getCategory` function and passing the `param` in category and where Iam using this function you can see I pass the parameter  `item.toLowerCase()`, its `item.toLowerCase()` if equal to `d.category` so it will give you the result of `item.toLowerCase()` against object, and you will get the against `item.toLowerCase()` result.

Comment: This code should work, `super()` should not affect this code.

Comment: Hi @madQuestions, sorry to bother you, I have updated the code and resloved all errors which you mentioned above and also you can check code is working on this link https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-water-wt9hpz?file=/src/Button.js:0-1169, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thank you!!! I really appreciate you taking the time to look into this!